# jquery .css effect isn't working with firefox

Tags: jquery, css

I have a horizontally sliding nav bar on my site, which is animated using a .css({left: ...}) function.

Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rH9Nd/

Here's the script I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.nav').mouseover(function() {
    $('.nav').css({ left: '140px' }, 100);
});
$('header').mouseout(function() { 
    $('.nav').css({ left: '0px' }, 100);
});
});
```

It works fine on Chrome, but on Firefox only part of the nav/header div extends, creating a weird overlap effect.  Not sure how to fix.

Also, as a side question - the first time the nav slides out, there's no animation.  It slides fine after it's been opened once, just not the first time.  Not crucial to fix, but it would be nice to have a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a CSS-only solution:

```
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 180px;
    margin-left: -180px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
    transition: 0.3s all;
}
.nav:hover{
    margin-left: -40px;
}
```

I've just checked and it's working in Safari, Chrome and Firefox. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d9ujp/3/

Comment: Yes this works perfectly.  I feel kind of dumb for not thinking of a pure css solution!  I was using a jquery click trigger previously, failed to realize that it was no longer needed...  Thanks!